# Search all JSON records that contain a particular attribute present using Kibana Console

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I have an Elastic Search data store where I am storing JSON data.

Say it has the following format:

```
{
"orderNumber": "1234"
"contactInformation": {
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName" : "Doe",
            "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com"
           }

}
```

Lets say contactInformation.email is an optional attribute and the attribute itself might not occur in all records. I want to retrieve all records for which the attribute email is present. What is the query that I will use in Kibana console for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "contactInformation.email"
    }
  }
}
```